# entity_get_form_display setComponent throws "plugin does not exist" regardless of type

Tags: entities, plugins

I'm trying to programmatically add a field to a custom bundle, and have it appear on the custom entity type. I'm using a `BaseForm` extended class, and have acquired an `entityManager` elsewhere using dependency injection.

Below is the `submitForm()` code I modelled, on how `FieldStorageAddForm::configureEntityFormDisplay()` etc. works:

```
$field_storage_values = [
  'field_name' => 'field_phone',
  'entity_type' => 'contact',
  'type' => 'string',
  'translatable' => false,
];
$field_values = [
  'field_name' => 'field_phone',
  'entity_type' => 'contact',
  'bundle' => 'organization',
  'label' => 'Phone',
  'translatable' => false,
];
$this->entityManager->getStorage('field_storage_config')
    ->create($field_storage_values)->save();
$this->entityManager->getStorage('field_config')
    ->create($field_values)->save();

entity_get_form_display('contact', 'organization', 'default')
  ->setComponent('field_phone', ['type' => 'string_textfield'])
  ->save();
entity_get_display('contact', 'organization', 'default')
  ->setComponent('field_phone', ['type' => 'string_textfield'])
  ->save();
```

This works fine for adding the field storage, and for associating the field instance with the bundle.

However, when it gets to the `entity_get_form_display()->setComponent()->save()`, the following exception is thrown:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Component\\Plugin\\Exception\\PluginNotFoundException: "The "string_string_textfield" plugin does not exist."
at /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 60
```

What's strange is that the same exception, quoting 'string', is seen for both `'type' => 'string_textfield'` and `'type' => 'text_text_with_summary'` (which doesn't even contain the word 'string'!) On the other hand, a nonsense value (e.g. 'string_string_textfield' or 'stringz_textfield') yields the exception with the nonsense value in full, no parsing. So there's *some* kind of detection/lookup going on, but it still can't find the relevant plugin.

What am I missing? What should the value of `'type'` be? I'm aware of e.g. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177913/the-string-plugin-does-not-exist but as you can see the value suggested there doesn't seem to work in this situation.

Comment: Query from #drupal IRC: replace "'type' => 'string'" in the field storage configuration? This results in "Attempt to create a field storage of unknown type textfield."

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've dug around and I think I've got a fix for this myself.

The first thing is to fix the code above; the two `'type'` entries SHOULD be different, and should match values available in the dropdowns in the admin UI:

```
entity_get_form_display('contact', 'organization', 'default')
  ->setComponent('field_phone', ['type' => 'text_textfield'])
  ->save();
entity_get_display('contact', 'organization', 'default')
  ->setComponent('field_phone', ['type' => 'string'])
  ->save();
```

The second thing is that the entity's `baseFieldDefinitions()` were also defining a 'view' formatter type and a 'form' formatter type, but for an undeletable base field:

```
$fields['name']->setSettings([
    'default_value' => '',
    'max_length' => 255,
    'text_processing' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', ['label' => 'above', 'type' => 'string'])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', ['type' => 'text_textfield'])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Originally, the form display here was also `'string'`. This is obviously nothing to do with the programmatic field adding itself, but when you run:

```
entity_get_*display(...)->setComponent(...)
```

the return value is `$this` i.e. the display object. So chaining `->save()` causes the ENTIRE display to be saved: including base fields. Only at this point did the broken configuration in the base fields suddenly cause a problem.

But, ensuring that:

- the `'type'` for form display ALWAYS matched a value available in the admin UI for content types
- and similar for view display
- and ensuring this across both the new field AND base fields

fixed the original problem. Phew.